# jQuery val to div

Tags: jquery, select

I want to send the value of a select to a div. But i can't find the solution to copy the text to  the .email_value, can somebody help me with this one. thank you already for your time.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#email_mail").change(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
    });
});


<div class="email_value"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/4PhHL/

```
<select id="email_mail">
    <option></option>
    <option value="test">test</option>
</select>

<div class="email_value"></div>


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#email_mail").change(function() {
        $('.email_value').text($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you both, so simple, i had a wrong way of thinking.
Strange thing is this doesn't work in my file, but i think there is another mistake in my file.

Comment: I got it, it needs to be in the header. I placed the script next to form.

Comment: Is it also possible to send it to a input field like: <input type="text" name="to" size="40" value="SELECTION"/>

Comment: Yes, see http://jsfiddle.net/4PhHL/3/. Add `class="email_value"` and change the line for `$('.email_value').val($(this).val());`

Comment: I have one more variant on this. This time i would like it when a person clicks on a btn then a word is directly going in to the input field. I tried a bit but no success. http://jsfiddle.net/6gNuc/1/

Answer (score 1):

Where you have:

```
alert($(this).val());
```

use

```
$('.email_value').text($(this).val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example of the same code opening an email mailto on select.
http://jsfiddle.net/4PhHL/2/

```
<select id="email_mail">
<option></option>
<option value="mailto:test@test.com">test</option>
</select>

<div class="email_value"></div>    

$("select").change(function () {
      $("select option:selected").each(function () {
      var myselect = $("select option:selected").val();
      var target = myselect;
 window.open(target);
          });
    });​
```